# Merge [multiplying] into [multiplication]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiplication) and [multiplying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiplying) both deal with multiplication. The former has more questions and a better tag wiki.

I propose:

- merge [multiplying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiplying) into [multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiplication)
- create a synonym from [multiplying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiplying) to [mutliplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutliplication)